# App freezes after it's opened from push notification - Cannot read property 'outlet' of undefined

Tags: android, ios, angular, push-notification, nativescript

#### Description

Nativescript application with Angular.

We have an application with multiple components which represent screens (e.g.: home screen, recap screen, photo screen, delayed upload screen). This application enables user to upload pictures.

User flow goes basically like this:

Home screen -> Photo screen -> Recap screen -> "Thank You" screen

with slight change if an user is on mobile data, than he is asked if he wants to delay photo upload and if so, he is redirected to the "Delayed upload" screen.

#### Problem

The problem is that when user navigates from "Delayed upload" screen to the home screen and then he exits app, after clicking on push notification, the app is opened on the home screen and completely frozen on both Android or iOS.

This does not happen when user after delaying stays on recap screen and exits the app or does not exit the app at all.

#### Error message

```
  ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlet' of undefined
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlet' of undefined
      at NSLocationStrategy.getRouteFullPath (file: src\webpack:\@davinci\union-mobile-app\node_modules\@nativescript\angular\fesm2015\nativescript-angular.mjs:3608:40)
      at NSRouteReuseStrategy.findValidOutletAndKey (file: src\webpack:\@davinci\union-mobile-app\node_modules\@nativescript\angular\fesm2015\nativescript-angular.mjs:5826:45)
      at NSRouteReuseStrategy.shouldDetach (file: src\webpack:\@davinci\union-mobile-app\node_modules\@nativescript\angular\fesm2015\nativescript-angular.mjs:5804:32)
      at ActivateRoutes.deactivateRouteAndItsChildren (file: src\webpack:\@davinci\union-mobile-app\node_modules\@angular\router\fesm2015\router.mjs:2919:61)
      at file: src\webpack:\@davinci\union-mobile-app\node_modules\@angular\router\fesm2015\router.mjs:2889:17
      at forEach (file: src\webpack:\@davinci\union-mobile-app\node_modules\@angular\router\fesm2015\router.mjs:181:12)
      at ActivateRoutes.deactivateChildRoutes (file: src\webpack:\@davinci\union-mobile-app\node_modules\@angular\router\fesm2015\router.mjs:2888:8)
      at ActivateRoutes.deactivateRoutes (file: src\webpack:\@davinci\union-mobile-app\node_modules\@angular\router\fesm2015\router.mjs:2901:25)
      at file:///data/data/sk.union.kasko.d...
```

#### Environment:

```yaml
OS: Windows 11 10.0.22631
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Shell: Not Found
node: 16.16.0
npm: 8.17.0
nativescript: Not Found

# android
java: Not Found
ndk: Not Found
apis: 26, 32, 33
build_tools: 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 31.0.0, 32.0.0, 32.1.0, 33.0.0
system_images:
  - android-26 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
  - android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
  - android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
  - android-32 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64

# ios
xcode: Not Found
cocoapods: Not Found
python: Not Found
python3: Not Found
ruby: Not Found
platforms: Not Found
```

#### Code

```
    scheduleDelayedUploadAlert(): void {
        LocalNotifications.requestPermission()
            .then(() => {
                LocalNotifications.schedule([{
                    id: this.DELAYED_UPLOAD_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                    title: this.translate.instant('notifications.delayedUpload.title'),
                    body: this.translate.instant('notifications.delayedUpload.body'),
                    ongoing: true,
                    at: moment().add(1, 'minutes').toDate()
                }]).then((scheduledIds) => {
                    console.log('Notification id(s) scheduled: ' + JSON.stringify(scheduledIds));
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log('scheduling error: ' + error);
                });

                LocalNotifications.addOnMessageReceivedCallback((notification) => {
                    console.log('Notification addOnMessageReceivedCallback, ID: ' + notification.id);
                    if (notification.id) {
                        timeModule.setTimeout(() => {
                            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                                console.log('Redirecting from notification call back to delayed upload screen');
                                this.router.navigate(['/selfInspection/delayedUpload']);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }).then(() => {
                        console.log('Listener added');
                    }
                );
            }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('No permission for notification');
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
```

#### Tests

I tried different versions of both Nativescript and Angular:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~14.2.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "~14.2.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.4.7",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.2",
    "@nativescript/appversion": "~2.0.0",
    "@nativescript/background-http": "^6.0.0",
    "@nativescript/camera": "^5.0.15",
    "@nativescript/geolocation": "^8.1.0",
    "@nativescript/local-notifications": "^6.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^4.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nativescript": "^8.4.0",
    "nativescript-clipboard": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.12",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~14.2.0",
    "@nativescript/android": "~8.4.0",
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.4.0",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.4.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.6",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~14.2.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.0",
    "codelyzer": "~6.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "platform-detect": "^3.0.1",
    "sass": "~1.39.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3"
  },
```

or

```json
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~16.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "~16.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "~16.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "~16.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "~16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~16.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~16.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "~16.2.12",
    "@nativescript/angular": "^16.0.1",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.6.1",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.2",
    "@nativescript/appversion": "~2.0.0",
    "@nativescript/background-http": "^6.0.0",
    "@nativescript/camera": "^5.0.15",
    "@nativescript/geolocation": "^8.1.0",
    "@nativescript/local-notifications": "^6.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator": "^4.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nativescript": "^8.4.0",
    "nativescript-clipboard": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.3.12",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~16.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~16.2.12",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.6.1",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.18",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~16.2.10",
    "@nativescript/android": "~8.6.2",
    "@nativescript/ios": "8.4.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.6",
    "codelyzer": "~6.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "fs-extra": "^9.0.1",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "platform-detect": "^3.0.1",
    "sass": "~1.39.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3"
  },
```

on multiple iOS and Android devices resulting in same behavior and error.

#### Expected behavior

After clicking on push notification, user should be redirected to the "Delayed upload" screen and app shouldn't be frozen on home screen.